# How to get the exact type of numeric columns incl. scale and precision?

Tags: c#, sql, datatable, ado.net, sqldatareader

Is there a way to know the exact type of a column in a `DataTable`? Right now I am doing this:

```
DataTable st = dataReader.GetSchemaTable();
foreach (DataColumn col in st.Columns)
{
   var type = col.DataType;
}
```

Now with `type.Name` I am able to find if it is a number(`int` or `decimal`..) or `string` but the problem is that I need the exact type, for example if in database let say column `Rate` is `NUMBER(4,3)` then here in my code I am only getting type as 'Decimal' and no information about the Format `4,3`.

Now the requirement is I need to format the values as per their type for eg. if `Rate=1.4` it should be shown as `0001.400` (according to the Format `NUMBER(4,3)`). Hence here since I do not have info I am not able to process the values further. Is there anyway to know the same?

Thanks

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/system.data.datacolumn.datatype.aspx

Comment: loop throught each row aka DataRow and using reflection getType of individual..

Comment: You need to look at the additional attributes on the column to determine that precisely. For example look at NumericPrecision and NumericScale properties http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getschematable%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: @Tim Schmelter : could be please through some light on how to use it.. I could find it in DataTable or DataColumn.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use `NumericPrecision` and `NumericScale`:

```
using (var con = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.MyConnectionString))
using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM dbo.Test", con))
{
    con.Open();
    using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    using (var schemaTable = reader.GetSchemaTable())
    {
        foreach (DataRow row in schemaTable.Rows)
        {
            string column = row.Field<string>("ColumnName");
            string type = row.Field<string>("DataTypeName");
            short precision = row.Field<short>("NumericPrecision");
            short scale = row.Field<short>("NumericScale");
            Console.WriteLine("Column: {0} Type: {1} Precision: {2} Scale: {3}", column, type, precision, scale);
        }
    }
}
```

More informations: [`GetSchemaTable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getschematable%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

I have tested it with a fresh table with a single column `NumberColumn` of type `numeric(4, 3)`:

```
Column: NumberColumn Type: decimal Precision: 4 Scale: 3
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was searching for. I have tried this in my code and got the desired values. Thanks a lot! +1

Comment: Just an add-on question. Is there any way to get specific column datarow from Schema tabe. For example only for Rate column how can I get the datarow. I did this: 1. Foreach Loop on schemaTbale.rows 2. schemaColName = row.Field<string>("ColumnName"); 3. If schemaColName="Rate" get all other data. However here for each column I am traversing the complete schemaTable.. Is there any better way to do this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @LittleMissSunshine: why is that a problem? You should not have dozens of columns anyway. You can use LINQ (which is also a hidden loop): `var row = tbl.AsEnumerable().First(r => r.Field<string>("ColumnName")=="Rate");`

Comment: Yyou are right in any case Schema table will be traversed aleast once for each column. LINQ and Loop in this case will be doing the same thing. And since no. of columns are limited it would not be hitting the performance that bad what I thought initially. Thanks again!

Comment: @LittleMissSunshine: performance should not be a problem at all since the whole `DataTable` is already in memory anyway and it's pretty small. However, for what it's worth, you could create a `Dictionary` from the `DataTable` to faster lookup the column by their names. So the key would be the column-name and the value the `DataRow`. You can use LINQ: `var dict=tbl.AsEnumerable().ToDictionary(r => r.Field<string>("ColumnName"), r => r);`

Comment: Is there any way to get the ProviderType using this solution ? (If I'm not mistaken, this field should contain the original SqlDbType, but it's always empty in my case).

Answer (score 0):

The DataTable returned by dataReader.GetSchemaTable() is the schema of the underlying result. This table contains, those many records as many columns in the underlying table. So you need to loop through the rows. Each row contains the metadata of the single column of the underlying table. You can get the metadata of the column as below

```
DataTable st = reader.GetSchemaTable();
                    foreach (DataRow row in st.Rows)
                    {
                        Console.Write(string.Format("ColumnName:{0} DataType:{1} Ordinal:{2} Precision:{3} Size:{4} Scale:{5}", 
                            row["ColumnName"], row["DataTypeName"], row["ColumnOrdinal"], 
                            row["NumericPrecision"], row["ColumnSize"], row["NumericScale"]));
                    }
```