# How to get NumericPrecision and Scale of a decimal from DataTable

Tags: c#, datatable

I need to get the exact type of a column in a `DataTable` in C#.
In a [simliar article on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24164439/how-to-get-the-exact-type-of-numeric-columns-incl-scale-and-precision) i found part of a solution:

```
DataTable st = reader.GetSchemaTable();
foreach (DataRow row in st.Rows)
{
    Console.Write(string.Format("ColumnName:{0} DataType:{1} Ordinal:{2} Precision:{3} Size:{4} Scale:{5}", 
        row["ColumnName"], row["DataTypeName"], row["ColumnOrdinal"], 
        row["NumericPrecision"], row["ColumnSize"], row["NumericScale"]));
}
```

This works for string and date so far.

But for decimal i always recieve `null`for precision and scale.
I need those values to create a new table in another database.

The `DataType` returned is `Decimal`.

In the MSDN documentation it says that NumericPrecision returns null if it is no numeric data type, but decimal is kind of numeric?

So how do i get the exact precision of decimal values from the DataSet? Or rather what am I doing wrong?

edit:

I am trying to create some new SQL database based on old .dbf files from a FoxPro application.
So i want to read the columns, and create them in SQL, therefore I need the exact type of the column.

I tried with the .dbf and a new sql database.
I created a table in both to know the exact type for sure, for both databases i get those null returns. There is only a problem with the decimal/numeric values, for string and DateTime i get the Size.
For the .dbf I use a OleDbConnection.
For the SQL I use a SqlConnection, I get null if I try it for each.

Comment: You have found a good post. Just follow it. ;)

Comment: What is your data type in the database?

Comment: To test it, i created both, numeric and decimal in my sql database, i get null for both. It's intresting that my code says both are "decimal" on the DataType
@Ian i read the post, and it works so far, my only problem is that i get a null value returned where no null is supposed to be and i dont understand why

Comment: That does not seem to follow the documentation... it should be OK if you have numeric with defined scale and precision

Comment: Is your datatype in the database nullable? If that is so, you would have nullable type also in the code I think.

Comment: Its still null, for nullable and for non nullable ...

Comment: Strange... I have no idea why... perhaps you could elaborate your post more, showing how you define your data in the database as well as your attempts and what you actually got from your attempts

Comment: What are you expecting the precision and scale to be?

Comment: Have you tried calling 'ExecuteReader' with the behaviour parameter set to KeyInfo?

Comment: Do you get the "right" values for `NUMERIC_PRECISION` and `NUMERIC_SCALE`, if you execute `"SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = @YourTableName"` -- (`" AND COLUMN_NAME = @YourColumnName"`)?

Comment: I expect the precision and scale to be what i set in the database, for example its:
numeric(18,5)
in the database.
With the CommandBehavior set to KeyInfo it stays null

Comment: @Corak: i need the values for every column in my table and i want thisto be able to work on more than one .dbf, because i will need to change some more in the future, i will clarify this in the question

Comment: Apparently, the dbf driver does not provide this information. What ADO.NET provider do you use? (OdbcConnection? OleDbConnection?)

Comment: @Heinzi -- good point. Just tested it on a MS SQL Server database/connection and got the right precision and scale as expected.

Comment: i use OleDb for the .dbf
But still i get the null values if i try it on my SQL database? Here I use the SqlConnection

Comment: Are you able to get the correct values when doing it in sql within your sql db?

Comment: Btw. for non-numeric/decimal fields (like (n)varchar for example), I get 255 for precision and scale. Never zero (or "null"). So it seems there's something else wrong.

Comment: @Sandmaann: It should work on SqlConnection. If it doesn't work with SqlConnection, provide a [mcve] and then submit a bug report on connect.microsoft.com.

Comment: `const string connectionString = "Server=[server];Database=[database];Trusted_Connection=True;"; using (var conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString)) using (var comm = conn.CreateCommand()) { comm.CommandText = "SELECT TOP(1) * FROM [Table]"; conn.Open(); using (var reader = comm.ExecuteReader()) { var st = reader.GetSchemaTable(); foreach (DataRow row in st.Rows) { /* Console.Write... */ } } }`

Comment: What version of .NET Framework are you using?.

Comment: For nchar and varchar precision and scale are also null...
I am using .net 4.5

Comment: What do you return if you go into SSMS and write: SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'YourTable'?

Comment: using the code Corak posted I get my desired values, from both sql and .dbf. Still i dont know why my code didn't work, because it does kind of the same, get the data from the database in a SchemaTable and look at the rows, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

From my experience with MySQL, the decimal datatype is numeric, but it can hold any precision or scale.  If the database you are trying to create doesn't have the decimal datatype, you may need to convert it to a different type of number and possibly guess what precision and scale you need.